# Android studio 3.0 Canary NPE after update

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, development-environment, android-studio-3.0

I'm updated Android Studio Canary from 2 to 3 ([current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plfv8.png)), and now I'm getting error when building project:

```
2017-06-15 16:32:00,831 [ thread 12]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactOutputImpl.getGeneratedManifest(AndroidArtifactOutputImpl.java:110)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:592)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$AdaptingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:397)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$PropertyCachingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:625)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SafeMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:647)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SupportedPropertyInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:670)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:356)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.getGeneratedManifest(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactOutput.<init>(IdeAndroidArtifactOutput.java:49)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.lambda$new$0(IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.java:48)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:71)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.java:48)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.lambda$new$0(IdeVariantImpl.java:51)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.<init>(IdeVariantImpl.java:50)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.lambda$new$4(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:80)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:71)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:80)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:63)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.<init>(AndroidModuleModel.java:125)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:202)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:219)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Before update everything worked fine. I tried to Invalidate/Restart with no success. Does anyone know the reason of this error and how to fix it?

Comment: AS version comes with its respective Gradle version. If your're using Canary 2, the Gradle should be 3.0.0-alpha2 and so on. Have you tried Clean, Rebuild and Make project?

Comment: @InfiniteLoops Sure. It is actually a confirmed bug, that will be fixed in Canary 6 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62544173

Answer (score 7):

Same happened to me on Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 after switching from one Git branch to another - no update of studio or plugin at that time.

Finally a combination of

- `gradlew clean assembleDebug` from console and
- `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` in Android Studio

executed approx. 3 times helped me but still don't know where the problem was.

Answer (score 5):

Its a known issue :[As Documented here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html)

Just do this

- **Build > Clean** Project from the menu bar.
- Then **sync your project** files with Gradle by clicking Sync Project from the
  toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me on Android Studio 3.0 beta 1. After I upgraded, I rebuilt the project and now the error no longer happens.